# Get exception errno 10054 when trying to get url status

Tags: python, urllib, urlopen

I am writing a script that check the status of several URL's
but every time that one of the site is down and I get the following error:

> error [errno 10054] an existing connection was forcibly closed by the
>   remote host

The script is like the following:

```
from urllib2 import Request, urlopen, HTTPError, URLError
import time
import tkMessageBox
import Tkinter as tk

user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'
headers = {'User-Agent': user_agent}
sites = ["http://www.google.co.il",] #I got my internal site so i wrote here google's site

root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()

while 1 == 1:
    for link in sites:
        ta = 0
        req = Request(link, headers=headers)
        try:
            page_open = urlopen(req)
        except HTTPError, e:
            print link, "First time error"
            time.sleep(20)
            try:
                page_open = urlopen(req)
            except HTTPError, e:
                print link, e.code
                print tkMessageBox.showerror(link, link + "  Server is unreachable!!")
                time.sleep(1)
        except URLError, e:
            print link, "First time error"
            time.sleep(20)
            try:
                page_open = urlopen(req)
            except HTTPError, e:
                print link, e.reason
                print tkMessageBox.showerror(link, link + "  Server is unreachable!!")
                log = open("log.txt", "a")
                log.write(time.ctime() + " " + link + " Site is UNREACHABLE!\n")
                log.close()
                time.sleep(1)
        else:
            print link
            time.sleep(1)
```

I tried to find a solution in the forum but didn't succeed.

Comment: When the site is down I would expect an error like that. You should handle it properly.

Comment: Are you saying you expect a different error, or are you expecting no error at all?

Comment: I except to get an error status code like 5xx that the program keep working.